# Crash handling events in c#

Tags: c#, .net, events, event-handling, runtime-error

I've got the following piece of code that is crashing my application and I don't understand why that's happening, so any help would be appreciated.

I've got the following callback that is called every time a grab is made from 1 camera.

```
/*Declaration*/ 
public delegate void CallbackFunc(IntPtr pUserData);
static CallbackFunc CallbackFuncPtr = new CallbackFunc(functionCallback);

static void  functionCallback(IntPtr pUserData)
{
    Console.WriteLine("callback done");
}
```

This callback is made from another function using the camera API every time a grab is detected, as follows:

```
RegisterCallback(m_hL, TCallbackType.STD_CALL, CallbackFuncPtr, IntPtr.Zero)
```

Doing that, the code works perfectly. The problem comes when I try to put a manual reset event, to control the number of frames that I want to grab.

The code, with the event handler is as follows:

```
/*Declaration*/ 
public delegate void CallbackFunc(IntPtr pUserData);
static CallbackFunc CallbackFuncPtr = new CallbackFunc(functionCallback);
static ManualResetEvent mre = new ManualResetEvent(false);

static void  functionCallback(IntPtr pUserData)
{
    Console.WriteLine("callback done");
    mre.Set();
}
```

And the function that does the callback adds an event WaitOne(), to wait for Set or timeout as follows

```
mre.Reset();
RegisterCallback(m_hL, TCallbackType.STD_CALL, CallbackFuncPtr, IntPtr.Zero);
mre.WaitOne(1000);
```

Finally, at the end of the code I have the methods to dispose and close the event:

```
mre.Dispose();
mre.Close();
```

The thing is, that when I add the event to my app, it crashes without throwing any exception. I've got Visual studio and the only error I get is: vshost32.exe has stopped working.

What could be failing?
Many thanks.

Comment: Try hooking up to the AppDomain.Current.FirstChance and AppDomain.Current.Unhandled exception events, see if they give any further clues; handle any exceptions within the callbacks, try/catch should be present on any *entry* point of your app, including event handlers

Comment: Thanks Sten. Yes I've got try / catch blocks in every call, but I didn't wanted to put all the stuff here to make the question clearer. I'll try with your suggestions.

Comment: Keep in mind that threads may have less-than-obvious "entry" points, when a new thread is started or when you invoke on another thread you can consider these entry points too

Comment: There are many ways in which the native camera code can crash.  Enable unmanaged debugging to see more.  Disposing the mre is certainly wrong, a crash is guaranteed when the WaitOne() call timed out and the callback is made later.  Trying to call Set() on a disposed object.  Do *not* ignore the return value of WaitOne().

Comment: uhm, if you call `Dispose` you don't need to call `Close`. And if you do, call `Close` before calling `Dispose`.